# Linking Error: Unresolved External Symbol....(Tried using XCode, VS, and GCC inline commands for Terminal)

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, linker

Basically in my driver.cpp, in my main method, I simply just for testing purposes, instantiate a object.

```
#include "SafeArray.h"
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    SafeArray<int> a1(4);
return 0;
}
```

Basically no matter which constructor I use, I get the unresolved external symbol for the constructor and destructor.

All files in the same directory I did: 
g++ -c SafeArray.cpp
g++ -o driver driver.cpp SafeArray.o

(linker errors)

And for VS and Xcode, i simply placed the files in their designated directory specified for header and source code, and when I build I get hit with the linker errors.

I have a feeling its something very simple im doing wrong, and I apologize in advance

Here's my header file:

```
#ifndef SAFE_ARRAY_H
#define SAFE_ARRAY_H

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SafeArray {

private:
    int low, high;
    T* p;
public:
    SafeArray();
    SafeArray(int i);
    SafeArray(int l, int h);
    SafeArray(const SafeArray &s);
    ~SafeArray();

    T& operator[](int i);
    SafeArray<T>& operator=(const SafeArray<T>& s);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, SafeArray<T> s);

};

#endif
```

Here's my .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SafeArray.h"
using namespace std;

template <class T>
SafeArray<T>::SafeArray() {
    low = 0;
    high = -1;
    p = NULL;
}

template <class T>
SafeArray<T>::SafeArray(int i) {
    low = 0;
    high = i - 1;
    p = new T[i];
}


template <class T>
SafeArray<T>::SafeArray(int l, int h) {

    if ((h - l + 1) <= 0) {
        cout << "Constructor error in bounds definition" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    low = l;
    high = h;
    p = new T[h - l + 1];
}

template <class T>
SafeArray<T>::SafeArray(const SafeArray& s) {

    int size = s.high - s.low + 1;
    p = new T[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        p[i] = s.p[i];
    }

    low = s.low;
    high = s.high;
}

template <class T>
SafeArray<T>::~SafeArray() {
    delete[] p;
}

template <class T>
T& SafeArray<T>::operator[] (int i) {

    if (i < low || i > high) {
        cout << "index " << i << " out of bounds" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return p[i - low];
}

template <class T>
SafeArray<T>& SafeArray<T>::operator=(const SafeArray<T>& s) {

    if (this == &s) {
        return *this;
    }

    delete[] p;

    int size = s.high - s.low + 1;
    p = new T[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        p[i] = s.p[i];
    }

    low = s.low;
    high = s.high;
    return *this;

}

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, SafeArray<T> s) {

    int size = s.high - s.low + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        os << s.p[i] << endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Comment: You're going to find this informative: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?s=1|3.8301)

Comment: @WhozCraig: And look at the upvotes .. exactly `777`, that's good luck supposedly.

Comment: 777 upvotes good luck indeed, thank you ! Will give this a read.